# Is there a word/phrase to describe when people think like the situation is normal while it is not normal

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to say "since they made it seem normal the coronavirus spread vastly".
Is there a better way to rephrase the part "making something seem normal"?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to rephrase the "spread vastly" part too.

Comment: Are you interested in a word that describes the person holding on to the idea that things are normal, or a word describing the person who is deliberately misleading others?

Comment: Isn't it just *normalizing* or *trivializing*?

Comment: What is the force of "like" in your title. Would substituting the relative pronoun "that" change its meaning? "Think like" requires an object e.g. "think like a child, an adult, a sportsman, a scientist". I wonder whether you should be posting on SE English Language Learners.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the usage. In political contexts, you can say *gas-lighting*. In colloquial contexts, you can say *new normal*. In other contexts, you can probably say *acclimating*. What you're describing is a scenario where people are experiencing fatigue to a heightened sense of emergency though, not people adjusting to the changed environment like a natural habituation.